# Migrating discourse server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, discourse

I'm migrating to a new server, so i've archived folder of pictures in `public/uploads/default`, zipped
and moved them to my new server and put to `shared/public/assets/default`.

When I'm doing cap deploy the capistrano removes them as

```
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset:.....
```

As far I understood, these pictures are not a part of manifest. So how I can keep these picture and integrate them into project? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your public assets in the `public/uploads/default` directory. This is the convention used by Discourse.